# XamlReader of XPS files throws cannot find resource

Tags: .net, xaml, xps, xpsdocument

I trying to read in a XPS file with XamlReader.Load ( XMLReader ). Some XPS files read in and I can walk through perfectly. One of the XPS files I am working, that displays correctly in IE, gives the following exception:

```
Cannot convert string '/png/1.png' in attribute 'ImageSource' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Cannot locate resource 'png/1.png'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush', Line 2309 Position 166.
```

The image file in question is in the XPS file at the location specified 'png/1.png' when I look at the file in IE or by browsing in with unZIP tool, the image file displays correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question involves setting up a ParserContext as an optional argument to Load().